# Is it possible to declare multiple artifactIDs per dependency?

Tags: java, maven, maven-2

I want to import [JODD](http://jodd.org) into my application.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jodd</groupId>
    <artifactId>jodd-core</artifactId>
    <version>3.6.6</version>
</dependency>
```

But I need a lot additional modules beside `jodd-core`. Well to be clear: a lot of `jodd-*` modules.

So my question is: Can I import multiple artifacts within one `<dependency></dependency>` like

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jodd</groupId>
    <artifacts>
       ...
    </artifacts>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Check also [Maven BOM](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html) files. Jodd project provides one that may be useful for you.

Comment: One more thing: check `jodd-joy` module, it has dependency on many jodd modules, so it might help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, maven is a bit verbose. Each `dependency` tag may hold only one `groupId` and `artifactId`.